# Remove a part of variable names in R column

Tags: r, dataframe, split, datatable, data-cleaning

I want to clean up an R variable column to get only the species names. I would like to remove the variable names after the 2nd "_".

This is my table :

| col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| Pelagodinium_beii_RCC1491_SRR1300503_MMETSP1338c20 | 4 |
| Acanthoeca_10tr_SRR1294413_MMETSP0105_2c10003_g1_i1 | 5 |
| Rhodosorus_marinus_UTEX-LB-2760_SRR1296985_MMETSP | 5 |
| Vannella_sp._CB-2014_DIVA3-518-3-11-1-6_SRR1296762_M | 3 |
| Florenciella_parvula_CCMP2471_SRR1294437_MMETSP134 | 5 |

I would like to have :

| col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| Pelagodinium_beii | 4 |
| Acanthoeca_10tr | 5 |
| Rhodosorus_marinus | 5 |
| Vannella_sp. | 3 |
| Florenciella_parvula | 5 |

I'm not really used to R and I didn't find the right method.

Answer (score 2):

```
df$col1 <- sub("^([^_]+_[^_]+)_.*", "\\1", df$col1, perl = TRUE)
df
```

```
                  col1 Col2
1    Pelagodinium_beii    4
2      Acanthoeca_10tr    5
3   Rhodosorus_marinus    5
4         Vannella_sp.    3
5 Florenciella_parvula    5
```

---

With `df` as follows:

```
df <- read.table(
  text =
'col1   Col2
Pelagodinium_beii_RCC1491_SRR1300503_MMETSP1338c20  4
Acanthoeca_10tr_SRR1294413_MMETSP0105_2c10003_g1_i1 5
Rhodosorus_marinus_UTEX-LB-2760_SRR1296985_MMETSP   5
Vannella_sp._CB-2014_DIVA3-518-3-11-1-6_SRR1296762_M    3
Florenciella_parvula_CCMP2471_SRR1294437_MMETSP134  5
',
  header = TRUE
)
```

Answer (score 1):

An option with `strsplit`:

```
df$col1 <- sapply(df$col1, function(i) paste0(strsplit(i, "_")[[1]][1:2], collapse = '_'))


# col1 Col2
# 1    Pelagodinium_beii    4
# 2      Acanthoeca_10tr    5
# 3   Rhodosorus_marinus    5
# 4         Vannella_sp.    3
# 5 Florenciella_parvula    5
```

Another way would be to use `word` from `stringr` package:

```
library(stringr)
word(df$col1, 1, 2, sep = "_") -> df$col1
```